# How does attending Military Academy work in time sequence?

Tags: en-garde

One can increase their Military Ability by attending the Military Academy.  The higher your MA the longer it takes to increase it.  How does attending the Academy work in conjunction with the timing sequence/orders?

For instance, during Week 1 could I do both courting a mistress and attend the Academy?  Or can I only do one or the other?

The main reason why I am confused is because attending the Academy is not listed in the activities in the time sequence section.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the wording of it and the fact that "Regimental Duties" falls under week long activities. I'd say that it is also week long activity.

So if you'd like to attend the academy you cannot do anything else that week.